# Proving that $x - \frac{x^3}{3!} < \sin x < x$ for all $x>0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, inequality

> Prove that $x - \frac{x^3}{3!} < \sin(x) < x$ for all $x>0$

This should be fairly straightforward but the proof seems to be alluding me.

I want to show $x - \frac{x^3}{3!} < \sin(x) < x$ for all $x>0$.  I recognize this shouldn't be too difficult but perhaps finals have fried my brain.

Comment: Use the Maclaurin series for $\sin x$, together with what you know about alternating series.

Comment: You only have to show sin(x) < x when x <= 1, because sin(x) is bounded

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/803127/proof-for-sinx-x-fracx33

Comment: Of possible historical interest are the references in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2780697/13130).

Answer (score 8):

You can use the Taylor expansion for $\sin (x)$ to get a rather quick solution. If you haven't met Taylor yet, then consider the functions $f(x)=x - \sin x$ and $g(x)=\sin (x) -x + \frac{x^3}{3!}$, compute the derivative, and conclude the functions are increasing for suitable $x>0$. Compute $f(0)$ and $g(0)$ to get the result.

Comment: You will have to show $cos(x) - 1 + x^2/2$ is positive which can be done by showing its derivative is positive. Then you will have killed two birds with one stone!

Answer (score 8):

**Recursive integration** We know that $$0\le\cos a\le 1\implies \sin t = \int_0^t\cos s ds < t$$ for $0\lt t\lt z\lt x$. Integrating over $\color{blue}{(0,z)}$ we get

$$1-\cos z=\int_0^z\sin tdt < \int_0^ztdt= \frac{z^2}{2}$$
that is for all $0<z<x$ we have,
$$\color{blue}{1-\frac{z^2}{2}< \cos z\le 1}$$
integrating again over $\color{blue}{(0,x)}$ we get

$$\color{red}{x-\frac{x^3}{6} = \int_0^x 1-\frac{z^2}{2} dz< \int_0^x\cos z dz=\sin x}$$
that is
$$\color{blue}{x-\frac{x^3}{6} <\sin x< x}$$

> continuing with this process you get,
> $$\color{blue}{1-\frac{x^2}{2}< \cos x< 1-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{24} }$$
> $$\color{blue}{x-\frac{x^3}{6} <\sin x< x-\frac{x^3}{6} +\frac{x^5}{5!}}$$

More generally for  $n\geq1$, by induction we get
$$\color{blue}{\sum_{k=0}^{2n-1}(-1)^k\frac{x^{2k}}{(2k)!}<\cos x<\sum_{k=0}^{2n-1}(-1)^k\frac{x^{2k}}{(2k)!}+\frac{x^{4n}}{(4n)!} }$$
$$\color{blue}{\sum_{k=0}^{2n-1}(-1)^k\frac{x^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!} <\sin x<\sum_{k=0}^{2n-1}(-1)^k\frac{x^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}+\frac{x^{4n+1}}{(4n+1)!}}$$

Comment: All your inequalities can be strict (as asked in question). If a continuous function is positive at some point, its integral is positive.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh sure you are right thanks . Is that a reason why someone gives me a down vote?

Comment: Don't worry about the downvotes! It's the work of some maniac downvoter and is another evidence of the non-mathematical theorem: "every serious user of this website gets a silent undeserved downvote". I have tried to compensate by giving a +1.

Comment: Btw you don't need the restriction of $<1$. You just need all your variables to be positive ie $0<z<x$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh thanks so far the hard of the downvoter has be undone. I have also correct the typos

Answer (score 6):

$\text{Here is a geometric proof for $\sin(\theta) < \theta$. Consider a unit circle as shown in the figure.}$
$\text{We then have that the area of the sector formed by $BC$ as }$
$$\color{red}{\dfrac12 \times OB^2 \times \theta = \dfrac12 \times 1^2 \times \theta = \dfrac{\theta}2}$$ $\text{which is greater than the area of triangle $OBC$, which is }$
$$\color{red}{\dfrac12 \times OB \times OC \times \sin(\theta) = \dfrac12 \times 1^2 \times \sin(\theta)}$$
$\text{We hence get that}$
$$\color{blue}{\dfrac{\sin(\theta)}2 < \dfrac{\theta}2 \implies\sin (\theta) < \theta}$$
$\text{The figure was drawn using GeoGebra on Ubuntu. Lets see if some one can come up with a}$
$\text{geometric/pictorial proof for $\color{green}{\theta - \dfrac{\theta^3}{3!} < \sin(\theta)}$.}$

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution without use a Taylor series.Observe that:

$\\ \\ \displaystyle \sin(3\gamma)=\sin(2\gamma)\cos(\gamma)+\sin(\gamma)\cos(2\gamma)=2\sin(\gamma)\cos^2(\gamma)+\sin(\gamma)(1-2\sin^2(\gamma))=2\sin(\gamma)(1-\sin^2\gamma)+\sin(\gamma)(1-2\sin^2(\gamma))=3\sin(\gamma)-4\sin^3(\gamma)\Rightarrow \sin^3(\gamma)=\frac{1}{4}\left(3\sin(\gamma)-\sin(3\gamma)\right)$
\begin{equation}
    \sin^3(\gamma)=\frac{1}{4}\left(3\sin(\gamma)-\sin(3\gamma)\right)
\end{equation}
Do it $\displaystyle \gamma=\frac{\phi}{3^k}$:

\begin{equation}
    \sin^3\left(\frac{\phi}{3^k}\right)=\frac{1}{4}\left(3\sin\left(\frac{\phi}{3^k}\right)-\sin\left(\frac{\phi}{3^{k-1}}\right)\right)
\end{equation}
Multiplying by $\displaystyle 3^{k-1}$:

\begin{equation}
    3^{k-1}\sin^3\left(\frac{\phi}{3^k}\right)=\frac{1}{4}\left(3^{k}\sin\left(\frac{\phi}{3^k}\right)-3^{k-1}\sin\left(\frac{\phi}{3^{k-1}}\right)\right)
\end{equation}

Applying summation on both sides of equality, we will have:

$\\ \\ \displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{n}3^{k-1}\sin^3\left(\frac{\phi}{3^k}\right)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{4}\left(3^{k}\sin\left(\frac{\phi}{3^k}\right)-3^{k-1}\sin\left(\frac{\phi}{3^{k-1}}\right)\right)= \frac{1}{4}\left(\left(3\sin\left(\frac{\phi}{3^k}\right)-\sin\left(\phi\right)\right)+\left(3^{2}\sin\left(\frac{\phi}{3^k}\right)-3\sin\left(\frac{\phi}{3}\right)\right)+...+\left(3^{n}\sin\left(\frac{\phi}{3^n}\right)-3^{n-1}\sin\left(\frac{\phi}{3^{n-1}}\right)\right)\right)  =\frac{1}{4}\left(3^{n}\sin\left(\frac{\phi}{3^n}\right)-\sin(\phi)\right)\Rightarrow \sum_{k=1}^{n}3^{k-1}\sin^3\left(\frac{\phi}{3^k}\right)=\frac{1}{4}\left(3^{n}\sin\left(\frac{\phi}{3^n}\right)-\sin(\phi)\right)\\ \\$

Take the limit:
\begin{equation*}
        \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}3^{k-1}\sin^{3}\left(\frac{\phi}{3^{k}}\right)=\frac{1}{4}\left(\phi-\sin(\phi)\right)
\end{equation*}

Notice, on the other hand, using the inequality $ \displaystyle \sin x \leq x $ and  using the infinite  arithmetic progression formula, follows:
$\\ \displaystyle \sin\left(\frac{\phi}{3^{k}}\right) \leq \frac{\phi}{3^{k}}\Rightarrow \sin^{3}\left(\frac{\phi}{3^{k}}\right) \leq \frac{\phi^3}{3^{3k}} \Rightarrow 3^{k-1}\sin^{3}\left(\frac{\phi}{3^{k}}\right) \leq \frac{\phi^3}{3^{2k+1}}\Rightarrow  \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}3^{k-1}\sin^{3}\left(\frac{\phi}{3^{k}}\right) \leq \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\phi^3}{3^{2k+1}}=\frac{\phi^3}{3}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{3^{2k}}=\frac{\phi^3}{3\times 8}\Rightarrow \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}3^{k-1}\sin^{3}\left(\frac{\phi}{3^{k}}\right) \leq \frac{\phi^3}{3\times 8} \Rightarrow \frac{1}{4}\left(\phi-\sin(\phi)\right) \leq \frac{\phi^3}{3\times 8} \Rightarrow \phi-\frac{\phi^3}{6}\leq \sin(\phi) $

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Taylor series of $\sin(x)$ about $x=0$:

$$\sin(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty {\frac {(-1)^n x^{2n+1}} {(2n+1)!}}$$

The first few terms are:

$$\sin(x) = x - \frac {x^3} {3!} + \frac {x^5} {5!} - \frac {x^7}{7!} + \dots$$

Thus, set:

$$x - \frac {x^3}{3!} < \sin x\\
x - \frac {x^3}{3!} < x - \frac {x^3} {3!} + \frac {x^5} {5!} - \frac {x^7}{7!} + \dots\\
0 < \frac{x^5}{5!} - \frac {x^7}{7!} + \frac{x^9}{9!} - \frac{x^{11}}{11!}+ \dots\\
$$

For $x>0$, this is true.

---

Similarly, for $\sin(x) < x$:
$$x - \frac {x^3} {3!} + \frac {x^5} {5!} - \frac {x^7}{7!} + \dots < x\\
\frac {x^3} {3!} + \frac {x^5} {5!} - \frac {x^7}{7!} + \dots > 0$$

Comment: To justify the inequalities (due to the alternating signs) you need to mention something about Leibnitz series.

Comment: It's not obvious to me why your last series is positive

Comment: Some of the signs need to be flipped in the last series; it should be
$$\frac {x^3} {3!} - \frac {x^5} {5!} + \frac {x^7}{7!} - \dots > 0.$$
@Mark The series is positive because it's an alternating series with terms that decrease in absolute value. You can see this by pairing the terms and recalling that $x$ is a small positive number:
$$\underbrace{\frac {x^3} {3!} - \frac {x^5} {5!}}_{­>0} + \underbrace{\frac {x^7}{7!}-\frac {x^9}{9!}}_{>0} + \dots > 0$$

Comment: Note that the Leibniz test applies only when terms decrease. For a general $x>0$ terms will decrease not starting from $x^3/6$ to $x^5/120$ but rather from a specific term depending on value of $x$. Thus this approach can not be utilized here. The right way is to use Lagrange remainder in Taylor's theorem and conclude. Also @Théophile, $x$ is a positive number not necessarily small.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Oh, indeed. It looks like I didn't put enough thought into my comment.