# Show that $\sin x$ lies between $x-x^3/6$ and $x \;$ $\forall x \in R$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

> Show that $\sin x$ lies between $x-x^3/6$ and $x \;$ $\forall x \in R$

I am getting:

$$\sin(x) = x - \frac{x^3}{3!} + R_4(x)$$

where $R_4(x) = \frac{\cos(c)x^5}{5!}$ for some $c$ between $0$ and $x$

I want to prove $R_4(x)\geq 0$ to arrive at the result $x-x^3/3 \leq \sin(x)$.

for:$$0 \leq x \leq \pi/2 \Rightarrow 0<c<\pi/2 \Rightarrow R_4(x)\geq 0$$ but for: $$-\pi/2 \leq x < 0 \Rightarrow -\pi/2 < c < 0  \Rightarrow R_4(x) < 0$$

How can I proceed with this ? There are many cases that I need to check

Comment: You can't prove it because the statement is false. For example take $x=-1$.

Comment: I assume for $x \geq 0$ you mean?

Comment: My textbook question reads - "Show that $\sin x$ lies between $x-x^3/6$ and $x$ $\forall x \in R$"

Comment: plot it and see exactly what you have to prove

Comment: http://fooplot.com/#W3sidHlwZSI6MCwiZXEiOiJzaW4oeCkiLCJjb2xvciI6IiMwMDAwMDAifSx7InR5cGUiOjAsImVxIjoieC14XjMvNiIsImNvbG9yIjoiIzAwMDAwMCJ9LHsidHlwZSI6MTAwMH1d

Comment: @FrankLu Are you sure? $x = -1$, $-1 - (-1)^3/6 = -5/6 \simeq 0.833$, and $\sin(-1) \simeq -0.84$. Those bounds seem to hold just fine.

Comment: @DuncanRamage The OP initially post "$x-x^3/3\leq\sin x\leq x,\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$".

Comment: @FrankLu Ah, that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The aim is to show that:

$$ x - \frac{x^3}{3!} \leq \sin(x) = x - \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^5}{5!} -\frac{x^7}{7!} + ...\leq x $$

For $sin x\leq x$ it suffices to use MVT:

$$\cos c =\frac{\sin x- \sin 0}{x-0}=\frac{\sin x}{x}\implies -1\leq \frac{\sin x}{x}\leq \implies \frac{\sin x}{x}\leq 1 \implies sin x\leq x$$

For  $x - \frac{x^3}{3!}\leq \sin(x) $ see here

[Proof for $\sin(x) > x - \frac{x^3}{3!}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/803127/proof-for-sinx-x-fracx33)

Answer (score 1):

This is an easy consequence of Taylor's theorem. We have via Taylor's theorem with Langrange's form of remainder $$\sin x=x-\frac{x^{3}}{3!}\cos\theta x$$ where $0<\theta<1$. Since $\cos\theta x\leq 1$ it follows that $$\sin x\geq x-\frac{x^{3}}{6},\,\forall x\geq 0$$ The inequality $\sin x\leq x$ for $x\geq 0$ is a fundamental property of $\sin x$ which is an immediate consequence of any suitable definition of $\sin x$. Thus for example the geometrical definition based on arc length of a circle implies $$x=\int_{0}^{\sin x} \frac{dt} {\sqrt{1-t^{2}}} $$ for $x\in(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ and gives the inequality directly as the integrand is greater than or equal to $1$.

---

More generally if $x\geq 0$ then Taylor's theorem can be used to show that $$x-\frac{x^{3}}{3!}+\dots+(-1)^{n-1}\frac{x^{2n-1}}{(2n-1)!}\leq \sin x\leq x-\frac{x^{3}}{3!}+\dots+(-1)^{n}\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$$ whenever $n$ is an even positive integer.