# Prove $\sin(x) > x - \frac{x^3}{3!} $ on $(0, \sqrt{20})$

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry, inequality, taylor-expansion

I'm having a bit of trouble with this because my attempted proof breaks down.

Proof:
It is sufficient to show that $f(x) =  \sin(x) - x + \frac{x^3}{3!} > 0$ on $I = (0, \sqrt{20})$. This is true if $f'(x)$ is strictly increasing on the interval and $f(0) \geq 0$. We can apply this property on the first and second derivatives as well. We note $f^{(3)}(x) = -\cos(x) + 1$. However I can only show that $f^{(3)}(x) \geq 0$ on $I$ since at $x = \frac{3\pi}{2}$ $f^{(3)}(x) = 0$

Comment: If this is intended mainly as a question asking for criticism of this specific proof (as opposed to asking for any proof for the claim), you should use ([tag:proof-verification]) tag. I will also point out related threads on this site: [Proof for $\sin(x) > x - \frac{x^3}{3!}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/803127) and [Proving that $x - \frac{x^3}{3!} < \sin x < x$ for all $x>0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/390899)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track. The function $f(x) =  \sin(x) - x + \frac{x^3}{3!}$ satisfies $f(0) = f'(0) = f''(0) = 0$ and
$$
 f^{(3)}(x) = -\cos(x) + 1 \ge  0
$$
with equality only at the points $x_k = \frac \pi 2 + 2 k\pi$, $k \in \Bbb Z$. It follows that $f''$ is strictly increasing on each interval $[x_k, x_{k+1}]$ Therefore $f''$ is strictly increasing on $\Bbb R$ and strictly positive on $(0, \infty)$.

Now you can conclude that  $f'$ and consequently $f$ are strictly increasing on $[0,\infty)$, and therefore $f(x) > 0$ for *all* $x > 0$.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

You can prove it directly:
$$f(x)=\sin(x) - x + \frac{x^3}{3!}>0,x>0;\\
f'(x)=\cos (x) -1+\frac{x^2}{2}>0 \iff \left(\frac x2\right)^2>\sin ^2 \left(\frac x2\right) \iff \\
\left(\frac x2-\sin \frac x2\right)\left(\frac x2+\sin \frac x2\right)>0 \iff \\
\frac x2-\sin \frac x2>0 \iff \frac x2>\sin \frac x2,x>0$$
Note:

1) $\cos (x)-1=-2\sin ^2 \left(\frac x2\right)$.

2) $x>\sin x, x>0$ is true, because $g(x)=x-\sin x$ is strictly increasing.

Answer (score 1):

Well, consider the series expansion of $\sin(x)$:
$$
\sin(x)=x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\frac{x^7}{7!}+\ldots
$$
So from your definition of $f(x)$, 
$$
f(x)=\frac{x^5}{5!}-\frac{x^7}{7!}+\ldots\geq \frac{x^5}{5!}-\frac{x^7}{7!}
$$
We can solve the inequality
$$
\frac{x^5}{5!}-\frac{x^7}{7!}>0\Leftrightarrow42-x^2>0\Leftrightarrow x<\sqrt{42}
$$
since $x>0$.

So when $0<x<\sqrt{42}$, your inequality is true.

I actually don't know where the $\sqrt{20}$ come from in the question. Anyone have a clue?

Comment: Thank you. I believe the $\sqrt{42}$ comes from being less than $2\pi$.

Answer (score 1):

For $x\ge0$, integrating from $0$ at each step:
$$
\cos(x)\le1\\
\Downarrow\\
\sin(x)\le x\\
\Downarrow\\
1-\cos(x)\le\tfrac12x^2\\
\Downarrow\\
x-\sin(x)\le\tfrac16x^3\\
$$
Therefore, for all $x\ge0$,
$$
\sin(x)\ge x-\tfrac16x^3
$$