# show that $x-x^{3}/6 < \sin x< x\text{ for }x>0$. ( taylor series)

Tags: taylor-expansion

the question in a random study problem says show that x - $\frac{x^3}{6} < sinx< x $ for $x>0$. ( taylor series). I am assuming the question means about x=0

I have tried finding the maximum error which you end up as lagrange $R (2) < \frac{x^3}{6}$ but that only lets me prove $sinx<x$

Comment: Integrate $1<\cos x$ three times from $0$ to $x$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust What is that inequality? Whenever is that true?

Comment: @fundamentalform: maybe $1>\cos x$ is more appropriate ;-)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proving that $x - \frac{x^3}{3!} &lt; \sin x &lt; x$ for all $x&gt;0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/390899/proving-that-x-fracx33-sin-x-x-for-all-x0)

Comment: @YvesDaoust Indeed! :-)

Comment: I you integrate , where do the constants go?