# If $x^2+y^2 = \sin(xy)$ find all $(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

> If $$x^2+y^2 = \sin(xy)$$ find all $(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2$

Since
,  $\sin(xy)≤1$ and $x^2+y^2≥0$ , hence: $x,y\in[-1,1]$.

I noticed that $(0,0)$ is a trivial solution. Also, since it's implicit, I can't sketch it's graph to even see number of solutions.

How can I proceed further ? If there are no more solutions, how can I prove so ?

Comment: *Hint:* $\sin(xy) \le |xy|$ and the AM-GM inequality.

Comment: Assume $y\ne 0$, divide through by $y^2$ and find that $(x/y)^2 \le 0$, hence $x=0$. Contradiction.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks ! I was focusing on equality so inequality didn't came to mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $x^2+y^2\geq 2|xy|$ (by $x^2+y^2\pm 2xy=(x\pm y)^2\geq0$), hence
$$\sin(xy)\geq 2|xy|.\tag{1}$$
On the other hand, we have (see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/390899/proving-that-x-fracx33-sin-x-x-for-all-x0?noredirect=1&lq=1), or the picture in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/75135/624428)) $$|\sin(xy)|\leq|xy|.\tag{2}$$
Combining $(1)$ and $(2)$ we obtain $2|xy|\leq \sin(xy)=|\sin(xy)|\leq|xy|$, hence $xy=0$. Plugging this back to the original equation we get $x^2+y^2=0$, thus $x=y=0$.

Yes. As Martin R points out in the comment: A slightly quicker way is to note that
$$x^2+y^2=\sin(xy)\leq xy\leq \frac{x^2+y^2}2,$$
which directly gives $x^2+y^2=0$ hence $x=y=0$.

Comment: Or $x^2+x^2 = \sin(xy) \le |xy| \le (x^2+y^2)/2$ which implies $x=y=0$.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks! I've added your method into my answer. Hope you don't mind. :-)

Answer (score 0):

To find all real solutions $(x, y)$ to the equation $x^2 + y^2 = \sin(xy)$, we can start by analyzing the properties of the equation.

First, note that $x^2 + y^2$ represents a sum of squares, which is always non-negative. On the other hand, the range of the sine function $-1 \leq \sin(xy) \leq 1$. This implies that for any real numbers $x$ and $y$, $\sin(xy)$ is bounded between $-1$ and $1$.

Now, let's consider the equation:

$x^2 + y^2 = \sin(xy)$

Since the left-hand side of the equation is always non-negative, and the right-hand side is bounded between $-1$ and $1$, the only way this equation can be satisfied for real numbers $x$ and $y$ is if $\sin(xy) = 0$ because $0 \leq 0 + 0 \leq 1$.

So, we have:

$sin(xy) = 0$

To find all solutions to this equation, we need to consider when $\sin(xy)$ is equal to zero. The sine function $\sin(u) = 0$ when $u$ is any multiple of $\pi$. Therefore, we have:

$xy = n\pi$

Where $n$ is an integer. Now, we can solve for $x$ and $y$ as follows:

If $n = 0$, then $xy = 0$, which implies that either $x = 0$ or $y = 0$ or both.

If $n$ is a non-zero integer, then we can solve for $y$ as $y = \frac{n\pi}{x}$.

So, the solutions to the equation $x^2 + y^2 = \sin(xy)$ for all real numbers $(x, y)$ are:

1. $x = 0$ or $y = 0$.
2. For non-zero integers $n$, $x$ can take any real value except $x = 0$, and $y$ is given by $y = \frac{n\pi}{x}$.

These are the solutions to the given equation for all $(x, y)$ in the real number domain.

Comment: "*Since the left-hand side of the equation is always non-negative, and the right-hand side is bounded between −1
 and 1
,* ***the only way this equation can be satisfied for real numbers x
 and y
 is if sin(xy)=0***" Why couldn't it be satisfied when sin(xy) is positive and less than 1 ?